# Gulp + Browserify + Babelify unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, gulp, syntax-error, browserify, babeljs

Im using Gulp to transform jsx/es6 using Browserify and Babelify but I'm getting the error: `Unexpected token (7:12) while parsing file: app.jsx`
What am I doing wrong? I can

**app.jsx** (7:12 is `<div>`)

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './header.jsx';

class App extends React.Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div className="container">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var bundler = watchify(browserify({
    entries: './client/components/app.jsx',
    transform: [babelify],
    extensions: ['.jsx'],
    debug: true,
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {},
    fullPaths: true
}));

function bundle(file) {
    if (file) gutil.log('Recompiling' + file);
    return bundler
        .bundle()
        .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, "Browserify Error"))
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/scripts'))
}
bundler.on('update', bundle);

gulp.task('build', function() {
    bundle()
});
```

and in my package.json I have:

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [["babelify", {"presets": ["es2015"]}]]
  }
```

***Update***

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
    gulp.src('./client/components/app.jsx')
        .pipe(browserify({
            extensions: ['.jsx'],
            debug: true,
            cache: {},
            packageCache: {},
            fullPaths: true
        }))
        .pipe(babelify({presets: ['es2015', 'react']}))
        .on('error', gutil.log.bind(gutil, 'Browserify Error'))
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./client/scripts/'))
});
```

I changed the gulp task but now I get the error:

```
Browserify Error [TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently not transforming the jsx into normal Javascript.

In your `Browserify` configuration you should have a `react` preset to achieve this. For you this would be:

```
"browserify": {
    "transform": [["babelify", {"presets": ["es2015", "react"]}]]
}
```

You'll also need to install this preset. `npm install babel-preset-react`

[More information about presets](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets)

[More information about react preset](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-react/)

Comment: @corasan Mmmh, could you try and put your browserify transform into the gulp task, or otherwise show in the original how the `babelify` gets created in the gulp task?

Comment: I updated my question with the new gulp task, I get a different error. `Browserify Error [TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk]`

Comment: Ah, your streams are a bit mixed up then. Can you try (at top) var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer'); and then after your source() pipe, pipe it into that?

Comment: That didn't work, I'll use browserify in my server.js instead of a gulp task, it used to work that way, I just wanted to gain more experience with gulp. I'll keep trying to make it work but right now I can't spend so much time in one problem and lose focus. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and in my case upgrading node just solved the problem.